# input paragraph and word from user, print words with same vowels as word from paragraph

Tags: python

[image: this is given question img]

I tried this question with regular expression ,but it doesn't provide me with required output

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far

Comment: import re
paragraph=input("Enter a paragraph : -  ")
word=input("Enter a word : -  ")
x=re.findall(word, paragraph)
print(x)

Comment: i tried to print matching word which user provide

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What would you expect with the following input words? "peacock" (beautiful contains _ea_ but doesn't contain _o:_); "suit" (beautiful contains both _u_ and _i_ but they're separated by a consonant); "urban" (beautiful contains both _u_ and _a_ but they're in the wrong order)

Answer (score 0):

The only situation in which a word isn't in the output list is if a vowel is in the input word but not in the word you are checking. You can use this fact like so:

```
def vowels_match(word, input_word):
    for vowel in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
        if vowel in input_word and not vowel in word:
            return False
    return True

paragraph = input('The paragraph is: ').split()
paragraph = [''.join([letter for letter in word if letter.isalpha()]) for word in paragraph]

while True:
    input_word = input('Input Word: ')
    print([word for word in paragraph if vowels_match(word, input_word)])
```

This outputs:

```
The paragraph is: It is a beautiful and lovely day today.
Input Word: and
['a', 'beautiful', 'and', 'day', 'today']
Input Word: peace
['beautiful']
```

Comment: This will not work in the "ea" example above

Comment: I ran it and got this output:

Comment: The paragraph is: It is a beautiful and lovely day today.
Input Word: and
['a', 'beautiful', 'and', 'day', 'today']
Input Word: peace
['beautiful']

Comment: yes, you're right, sorry; but see my comment to the OP

Comment: Yes, it's not the same vowels but I think this is what they meant